# ¿Como asignar valores a un jar desde otro?

Tags: java

La idea es la siguiente:
Tengo un `.jar` que crea números aleatorios entre 2 que le doy, entonces debo de llamarlo desde otro `.jar` que estoy creando y recoger sus datos en un `array`.

---

Este es el codigo que tengo

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Double> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String so = System.getProperty("os.name");
            if (so.equals("Linux")) {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Ejercicio3/aleatorio.jar 3 100");
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String linea = "";
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    numeros.add(Double.parseDouble(linea));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
                }

            } else {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Ejercicio3/aleatorio.jar 3 100");
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String linea = "";
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    numeros.add(Double.parseDouble(linea));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Este el el ejercicio aleatorio

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        double resultado = 0;
        boolean parar = false;
        while (!parar) {
            if (num1 > num2) {
                resultado = Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2;
            } else {
                resultado = Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("" + resultado);
    }
}
```

No hay errores de compilacion pero no consigo que rule

Comment: que es un jar? un programa?

Comment: un .jar es un proyecto java echo ejecutable

Comment: y cual es el problema??? si requiere pasar parametros use `java -jar Ejercicio3/aleatorio.jar 3 100` donde 3 y 100 son los números entre los que desea calcular números aleatorios, pero el programa `aleatorio.jar`en el método `main` debe leer los parametros del arreglo `args[]`

Comment: uf y eso como es jaj yo le tengo puesto 2 int

Comment: @isaac te he ampliado la pregunta con el codigo del ejercicio aleatorio y con como he puesto este ejercicio actualmente, Nose si en cm c\ es necesario o no "cmd /c java -jar Ejercicio3/aleatorio.jar 3 100"

Comment: Me parece a mi o tenés un bucle infinito:  while (!parar) {

Comment: si se debe colocar el paht completo de donde se ubica el jar `c:/carpeta1/../Ejercicio3/aleatorio.jar 3 100`, y revise el comentario de Juan, el ciclo del programa que calcula los aleatorios es infinito.

Comment: @isaac lo se por eso la idea es cortar la llamada a los 10 segundos